# QNX QCC linker includes file timestamps

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, qnx

Is there a flag to pass into the linker which will **NOT** include each file's timestamp in the `library.a` output?

We are creating a library with the qcc `-A` parameter and when it does this it gathers all the compiled files into the library correctly but it always adds certain file information (file size, timestamp, etc).  The problem is that we cannot create exactly the same binary after a clean since the timestamp is part of the binary

Output includes a line like this for every `.o` in the project:

```
DirReader.o/    1299620472  0     0     100666  15364
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of QCC and Neutrino?

Are you using any `__DATE__` or `__TIME__` macros in your code? Those are expanded and will change the checksum of your binary.

You can always do something like the following in your make file:

```
DEFINES += -DSW_COMPILE_DATE="'TestDate'
```

Then just use `SW_COMPILE_DATE` instead of `__DATE__` or `__TIME__`, and you can control what shows up in your binary.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html has more information about Standard Predefined Macros.